# GravityForms Data Manipulation help needed

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have searched all over the internet and I have had no luck in finding the answer to my question. I hope this has not specifically been posted yet, but if you can point to where i can find the answer I would appreciate it.

I have set up a site that I am building into a fantasy golf site. I am using GravityForms as my form plugin. I have all the other features I want set, set up and need help with this last thing.

```
id   lead_id form_id field_number   value
1       1      1        1           Hosker
2       1      1        7           b**********@yahoo.com
3       1      1        6           Hyundai Tournament of Champions
4       1      1        3           Adam Scott
5       1      1        4           Harris English
6       1      1        5           2014-01-02 23:59:47
7       1      1        8           5b409692-e9ed-486e-8d77-7d734f1e023d
```

This is what my form submission gets posted as in the database. I would like to be able to take all of the data from this form and do an sql query and put it all in one row. Is that possible? The two columns that I will need to build my query around would be from lead_id and value where the value that I will be basing the query on is in row 7. The only value that I will know is in row 7. Thanks in advance for your help.

This is the result I am looking for

```
id   lead_id form_id field_number   value     value                  value                                value          value            value                      value
1       1      1        1           Hosker    b**********@yahoo.com  Hyundai Tournament of Champions    Adam Scott    Harris English    2014-01-02 23:59:47    5b409692-e9ed-486e-8d77-7d734f1e023d
```

Comment: I got the answer I needed from this additional post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152452/query-a-specific-value-with-pivot-table-mysql

Answer (score 1):

I would hook into the gravityform submission action and then perform whatever logic is required at that point to do the insert into the database.

```
add_action("gform_after_submission", "on_gform_submit");
```

Then create a function to accept the entry as an argument.

```
function on_gform_submit($entry){

}
```

Inside of this function `$entry` is an array that has the ID of each field (as per the back end) as the key. So if for instance `message` had an ID of `10`, then it would be

```
$message = $entry['10'];
```

Then when you're done, simply input the data using a standard SQL Insert statement

Comment: I am not looking to affect the submission entry, unless that is the only way that I can achieve the result I am looking for. I have edited my original post to show the result i would like acheived.

Comment: @hosker This doesn't affect the entry what so ever. Inside of the `on_gform_submit()` function, access the array elements and save it into the database. When done, just let the script continue, it will still save it's proper form in the database, and you can do your logic to perform your `SQL Insert`