# Query a specific value with Pivot Table mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, pivot-table, gravity-forms-plugin

I have searched all over the internet and I have had no luck in finding the answer to my question. I hope this has not specifically been posted yet, but if you can point to where i can find the answer I would appreciate it.

I was able to take the following table data below:

```
id   lead_id form_id field_number   value
1       1      1        1           Hosker
2       1      1        7           b**********@yahoo.com
3       1      1        6           Hyundai Tournament of Champions
4       1      1        3           Adam Scott
5       1      1        4           Harris English
6       1      1        5           2014-01-02 23:59:47
7       1      1        8           5b409692-e9ed-486e-8d77-7d734f1e023d
```

And get the result below using this query string:

```
SELECT id, lead_id, form_id, 
MAX(case when field_number = 1 then value end) username, 
MAX(case when field_number = 7 then value end) email, 
MAX(case when field_number = 6 then value end) tournament_name, 
MAX(case when field_number = 3 then value end) primary_golfer, 
MAX(case when field_number = 4 then value end) backup_golfer, 
MAX(case when field_number = 5 then value end) date, 
MAX(case when field_number = 8 then value end) tournament_id 
FROM `wp_rg_lead_detail` GROUP BY lead_id



id   lead_id form_id field_number   value     value                  value                              value          value            value                      value
 1      1      1        1           Hosker    b**********@yahoo.com  Hyundai Tournament of Champions    Adam Scott    Harris English    2014-01-02 23:59:47    5b409692-e9ed-486e-8d77-7d734f1e023d
```

I just want that query string to only pull the related data when the value of the tournament_id column equals a specific value. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this query. I think you can use the `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT id, lead_id, form_id, 
MAX(case when field_number = 1 then value end) username, 
MAX(case when field_number = 7 then value end) email, 
MAX(case when field_number = 6 then value end) tournament_name, 
MAX(case when field_number = 3 then value end) primary_golfer, 
MAX(case when field_number = 4 then value end) backup_golfer, 
MAX(case when field_number = 5 then value end) date, 
MAX(case when field_number = 8 then value end) tournament_id 
FROM `wp_rg_lead_detail` GROUP BY lead_id
HAVING tournament_id = '5b409692-e9ed-486e-8d77-7d734f1e023d'
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06bbb/3/0) In the sqlFiddle I have sample data for 2 different tournament_id and the `HAVING` clause is applied so that only values for that tournament_id would be returned, you can try removing the HAVING and see that it returns 2 rows.

Your Group By is not standard since you're selecting id and form_id as well. I suggest you drop the the id or use MIN(id) or MAX(id) and `GROUP BY lead_id,form_id`

Comment: that works for me, however I was able to filter my results within my foreach loop a different way, but this will essentially save me a step. Thanks

Comment: the lead_id is standard per form entry. as of right now it works for me and with both tournament_id's I have data for, I get the correct results

Comment: do you know if it is possible to have a query within a MAX() select? I need to pull an additional value from a different table based upon the value in primary_golfer and backup_golfer columns.

Comment: not sure what you mean but you could always compare a single value to a (SELECT something from sometable) so long as the SELECT returns a single value. Or instead of a value you can always (SELECT somevalue from some table) for the `then` so long as that SELECT also returns one value. Best is just to try it.

Comment: Ok, the above query gets me all but 2 values that I need. I have a additional table that I need the following values first_name, last_name, and player_id. I have the SQL statement of "SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) as player_name, player_id from 2014_profiles" that returns a list of players with their respective player_id. I would like to add to the above query two additional columns to get the player_id where primary_golfer = player_name and backup_golfer = player_name

Comment: I think you might have to user INNER JOIN like this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/763784/4/0)

Comment: that totally worked from me, thanks again, you have been extremely helpful.

Comment: okay, after reviewing all of the data that I need to pull for this query, I need to add an additional table which is 2014_leaderboard and I need to join it on the value of 2014_leaderboards.player_id = primary_player_id. I have tried a few things and got no values returned

Comment: what does 2014_leaderboard look like like column names and what value you want?

Comment: here is what the table looks like(which is in my next post), I did an export of the table into and sql query for you to get an idea. I basically just want the round1_score, round2_score, round3_score, round4_score, player_id, player_money, player_score, player_position, I want to oder on player_position

Comment: where's the export? i don't see a link.

Comment: I do not have data in the table yet, but have the following columns
    `id`, `tournament_id`, `player_id`,`player_money`, `player_score`, `player_position`,`player_points`,`player_strokes`,`round1_score`,`round1_strokes`,`round1_thru`,`round1_eagles`,`round1_birdies`,`round1_bogeys`,`round1_double_bogeys`,`round1_other_scores`

the round1 columns continue for round 2 - round 4

Comment: like this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62817/2/0), I just put SELECT `T4.*`, but you can select individual columns you like if you want from `T4`

Comment: If you have no data in the table maybe you want to use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` that way you'll always get data for the other tables back and NULL values for T4 (2014_leaderboard)

Comment: the query you have set up returns 14 rows, when I should only have 11 returned. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: can you sqlfiddle your data?

Comment: my data is too large to fiddle. and I need to import all of it due to my sql query having to parse it

Comment: not sure why you're getting 14 rows instead of 11, you might have to example the returned data carefully to be able to tell why.

Comment: this is all from the SQL fiddle you set up

Comment: 29 5 1 Sbritt31 sbritt31@hotmail.com Hyundai Tournament of Champions Ryan Moore Jimmy Walker 2014-01-02 23:59:47 5b409692-e9ed-486e-8d77-7d734f1e023d 94c4646a-c6f7-4bc8-9543-ac7e93814cd7 2db60f6e-7b0a-4daf-97d9-01a057f44f1d 10 5b409692-e9ed-486e-8d77-7d734f1e023d 94c4646a-c6f7-4bc8-9543-ac7e93814cd7 170000.00 -13 10 75 279 -6 67 18 1 5 1 0 0 -2 71 18 1 4 4 0 0 -1 72 18 0 5 4 0 0 -4 69 18 0 7 3 0 0

Comment: okay so it will not format well. I will set up an out put page tomorrow on my site to display this data and I will post the link here

Comment: check to make sure all your playernames are unique because we're joining on names if they have similar names that might be a problem

Comment: also T4(2014_leaderboard) can not have multiple entries for a single player_id because we're joining on that, if it has multiple entries for a signle player_id it'll join them and that might be why we're getting extra rows. unless 2014_leaderboard has a tournament_id column then we can add a where tournament_id = 'someId'

Comment: Good catch, I totally forgot that I needed to have the tournament_id included as well.

Comment: Here [link] http://dev.purefantasygolf.com/stackoverflow-help/ is the code I have for my SQL query, when I run this I get 83 rows from the DB when I should only get 44.

Within this query the only unique column is lead_id where it can only have 1 value per row. I have been able to get this code to execute and produce the results I am looking for with additions to this code. I however now need to get only the correct rows from the database and SUM(player_money) from my over all leaderboard.

How would I get this so that only 1 row per column lead_id is being outputted?

Comment: I can't really tell you how because i can't see your data.

Comment: If you click the link again, I've added my query to the page

Comment: is that data from multiple tournaments? because I don't see a HAVING tournament_id = 'somevalue' in your query.

Comment: Yes, it is data from all the tournaments from thus year

Comment: Do you have a tournament_id in your 2014_leaderboard table? If you do you might have to add `AND T1.tournament_id = T4.tournament_id` at the very end.

Comment: Okay, so I have 5 tournaments now in my T4 table and I am not getting all of the results from the tournaments. I should be getting 11 results for each tournament. I am only getting 4 for the first one. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, try:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE tournament_id = specific_value;
```

Comment: I understand how to do that, but the form data does not originally have the column name tournament_id it has the default column name of value. It is only when I create the above query that I get the column heading tournament_id. How do I query and concatonate the rows I need with the value from one of the rows being the tournament_id value?

Comment: Perhaps I still don't understand: `SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE value = specific_value` work any better? I replaced tournament_id with the "value" row header. I don't think I know what you mean by concatonate the rows with the value.

Comment: when I create the query with value = '5b409692-e9ed-486e-8d77-7d734f1e023d' all the other columns have a value of NULL.

Comment: It seems to me if you have that table, using that query should return `id lead_id form_id field_number value``7 1 1 8 5b409692-e9ed-486e-8d77-7d734f1e023d` Perhaps I'm missing some information from you. Sorry, wish I could have been more help :/